# Join function in knockout js observableArray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is there a way to perform the javascript join function in a observableArray?

In javascript i can do the following:

```
var a = ["1", "2", "3"];

var p = a.join(',');
```

and p would be "1,2,3" but with knockout i cant found a way to do this action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var x = ko.observableArray(["1", "2", "3"]);

var p = x().join(',');
```

Comment: Damn... sorry for the question... it was really dumb to not try the "()".

Comment: What if the observableArray is an array of objects (id, name) and i whant to join by the id?

Comment: @Phoenix_uy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/javascript-perform-join-on-value-in-object-array