# Append comma (,) plus html if td has any text otherwise append only html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working in some jQuery code and I've some doubts. This is what I've until now:

```
var html = '';
data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    html += index !== data.entities.length-1 ? value.pais + ', ' : value.pais;
});

var rowUpdate = $('#distribuidorBody').find('#td-' + data.idToUpdate);
rowUpdate.text() !== "" ? html += ', ' + html : html;
rowUpdate.append(html);
```

The big idea: I can execute the same code several times so the first time `rowUpdate` doesn't have any values so `text()` is empty and I will get some output in HTML as for example: `Country1, Country2, Country3` and so on then `rowUpdate.text()` should be `Country1, Country2, Country3`. So if second time I ran the same code and add `Country4, Country5` then `rowUpdate.text()` should be `Country1, Country2, Country3, Country4, Country5`. Is my code right? If not any help? I'm not getting errors but I need to understand if what I'm doing is right or wrong. Also I like to know what this code does:

```
rowUpdate.text() !== "" ?: html += ', ' + html;
```

It's not mine I see it around it but doesn't know what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A probably better solution is to build up an array of the items that you want to display, and then use `.join(', ')` to create the text:

```
var items = [];
data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    items.push(value.pais);
});
var displayText = items.join(', ');
$('#distribuidorBody').find('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(displayText);
```

Now, the last line, because `'#td-' + data.idToUpdate` is an ID, it should be unique to the page (if not, you should make it so that it is).  If or once that is true, you can shorten it to

```
$('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(displayText);
```

Comment: and what about if I have previous text as I mention in my post? It will be keep or will be overwrite? Also thinking, now I'll need to append some `<span class="countryToDelete"></span>` to each items on the array since later I'll allow remove them by click on each one, how?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `forEach` could be `map`.

```
var text = data.entities.map(function(v){ return v.pais }).join(', ');
```

or `reduce`:

```
var text = data.entities.reduce(function(a, b){ return {pais: a.pais +', '+ b.pais}}).pais;
```

and for the ternary operator, you need two expressions: `condition ? expr1 : expr2` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var rowUpdate = $('#distribuidorBody').find('#td-' + data.idToUpdate);
text = (rowUpdate.text() !== "") ? ', ' + text : text;
// alternative with if
// if(rowUpdate.text() !== "") text = ', ' + text ;
rowUpdate.append(text);
```

---

**Update:** add `span` on each value

```
var text = data.entities.map(function(v){ return '<span class="countryToDelete">' + v.pais + '</span>'  }).join(', ');
```

Comment: This answer is the nicest one +1. It's how [I'd do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/javascript-perform-join-on-value-in-object-array/16607599#16607599). To OP - don't append a `span class` and don't find based on `$("#id-" +text` - those are both horrible - you're querying your presentation layer for business logic. Instead store the items in an array and add click handlers to each one. Map to elements and then append handlers to them - not to strings. Keep a reference to the row element itself rather than a selector to select it with.