# Cannot join values from Object in js

Tags: javascript

I know this is pretty silly, but:

```
window.temp1.targetInterests
```

Returns me:

```
Object {Famosos: "Famosos", Musica: "Música", Humor: "Humor"}
```

I tried to `join` it:

```
window.temp1.targetInterests.join('/')
```

and [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/javascript-perform-join-on-value-in-object-array) it:

```
window.temp1.targetInterests.map(function(elem){
    return elem.name;
}).join(",");
```

but it keeps returning me

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: what are you trying to join ?

Comment: `join` is an array method, not an object method.

Comment: You have no `name` property?

Comment: I'm trying to join `window.temp1.targetInterests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to join the keys together:

```
var joinedKeys = Object.keys(window.temp1.targetInterests).join(",");
```

If you want the actual values, you'd have to iterate the object:

```
var joinedValues = [];
for (var key in window.temp1.targetInterests) {
    joinedValues.push(window.temp1.targetInterests[key]);
}
joinedValues = joinedValues.join(",");
```

Comment: Thanks. I structured my object badly. It worked for me.