# Convert array of object to once string with only values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array of object as below

```
const result = [
    { email: 'me@example.com' },
    { email: 'c@examples.com' }
];
```

Expected Output :

```
"me@example.com, c@examples.com"
```

How can i get the desired output?

Comment: this is a very basic question, you should be able to figure it out on your own

Comment: it would duplicate question, anyway `result.map((v)=>{return v.email}).join(', ')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform .join on value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/perform-join-on-value-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

[image]`result.map(({email}) => email).join(', ')`

iterate thru the array and join it.