# How can I do to join value of array of dicts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like that :

```
a = [{"country":"Colombia","date":"1995"}, {"country":"China","date":"1995"},{"country":"USA","date":"1992"}]
```

And what I want is that : `"Colombia-China-USA"`

I thought to use `join('-')` but a is not like that : `a = ['Colombia', 'China', 'USA']`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: use map to get the array of countries and then join `a.map(({country}) => country).join('-')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277437/13583510

Comment: @cmgchess: just out of curiosity, how `a.map(({country}) => country)` is better than `a.map(x => x.country)`?

Comment: @gog it's not 'better' in this case, just preference. (there are cases where destructuring provides actual functionality within the callback, ie filtering out keys)

Comment: @gog it is semantically the same, cmgchess' version does the unpacking in the parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform .join on value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/perform-join-on-value-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: @gog in this case yours is actually shorter

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can get country names as an array using map.

```
const coutries = a.map((item) => item.country)
```

Now the output array will be like this.

['Colombia', 'China', 'USA']

then you can join that array using join method.

```
const coutries = a.map(item => item.country).join('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple JavaScript:

```
let a = [{"country":"Colombia","date":"1995"}, {"country":"China","date":"1995"},{"country":"USA","date":"1992"}];
let b = "";
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b+=a[i]["country"];
    if(i!=a.length-1) b+="-";
}
console.log("b = "+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also reduce method like this:

```
const listCountries = a.reduce((list, curr, index) =>{ 
    if( index === 0) { list = list+ curr.country;} else{ list = list +"-"+curr.country;};
return list;
},"");
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce